# What is limiting the width of element?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, width

I've created an horizontal CSS/HTML menu with some jQuery to move elements into a dropdown if the parent is not wide enough to keep everything on one line. When elements move into the `#dropdown` the resulting `<ul>` appears to have its width limited and I don't understand what it is doing that?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wright_jamie/wf7h8/)

Comment: Add width to the ul or add `white-space: nowrap;` to it. Since this is a absolute positioned element it doesn't know how much space should it take if it's not told so.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in** the question, please.

Comment: I would put some code in, but I honestly don't know which part of my code to paste! Hence using the Fiddle. I realise it's not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 7 of your fiddle, you are dynamically creating a `<ul>` which contains the menu items that do not fit into your menu. It's that `<ul>`'s width that is too small for the text, which makes the text go to multiple lines. If you give that menu a style of `white-space:nowrap`, it will make the `<ul>` take up as much width as it needs. The code below does it inline, but it's just an example. http://jsfiddle.net/wf7h8/1/

```
var dropDownHTML = "<li id='dropdown'><a href='#'>Menu</a><ul style='white-space:nowrap;'></ul></li>";
```

Comment: That solves it, thanks.
What I don't understand is why it picks the width that it does?

Comment: I think @drip is right. Since it is an absolutely positioned element, it will only take  up as much width as it needs. What I found by simply  looking at your fiddle is that the ul is always just wide enough to fit the longest word on the menu without making it overflow.

Comment: Great spot. I've played around with word length and you're right